# Alternative proof that $\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R} : \alpha^2 = 2$

Tags: real-analysis

The question if there exists $b \in \mathbb{R} : b^2 = 2$ [has already been asked and answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1319580/176956). I am interested in a possibility of proving this statement using the axiom of completeness on a *closed set* A.

If $A$ is a closed set $A=\{x : a \le x \le b \, , a,b \in \mathbb{R}, a < b \}$,

First we want to see that $b = sup A$.

i) $b >= x , \forall x \in A$ - obvious from definition of $A$

ii) $\nexists c \in \mathbb{R}, c \ge x \,, \forall x \in A : c < b$ - there is no number $c$ that is an upper bound of $A$ *and* also smaller than $b$.

If $c < b$ we can define $\epsilon \in [0, b - c]$. From this follows $c + \epsilon \le b$. From the definition of $A$ we have that $b \ge x \Rightarrow x \in A$. As a consequence $c + \epsilon \in A$.

This means that $\exists x_\epsilon = c + \epsilon \in A : x_\epsilon > c$, so $c \ngeq x \forall x \in A$ - if we choose $\epsilon > 0$ like this then $c$ is not an upper bound at all, which means that there is no such $c$ that is an upper bound of $A$ and $c < b$ leading to  $b = sup A$.

Second, if we define $A$ like this:

$A' = \{x^2 : x^2 \le 2 \}$

then based on $b = sup A$ from above we can see that $b = 2$ for $A'$, in which case there must exist $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that solves $x^2 = 2$, otherwise $A'$ has no supremum, which violates axiom of completeness for closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this valid?

Comment: Assuming that $A'$ is closed is a petitio principii. That's exactly what you want to show. (Well, actually it's a bit more than the existence of an $x$ with $x^2 = 2$.)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Thank you, I see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you want $\{x : x^2 \le 2 \}$, whose sup is $\sqrt2$, not $\{x^2 : x^2 \le 2 \} = [0,2]$, whose sup is $2$.

Moreover, proving that $\{x : x^2 \le 2 \}$ is closed is precisely equivalent to what you want to prove, that is, the existence of a solution to $x^2=2$.

Comment: @egreg  I think even without the considtion $x \geq 0$ the set is bounded, as  it is bounded below by   $ - \sqrt(2) $ and from above by $ \sqrt(2) $

Comment: @lhf Yes, I was thinking to something else; sorry. In any case I had already upvoted your answer.